# Most elegant way to round a date to a dynamic unit of time, using only JDK 6

Tags: java, calendar, timezone, jodatime, scjp

I'm trying to do an elegant round method that only use the JDK methods and leverage the TimeUnit class of that JDK.

I've made the following code:

```
   /**
     * Get the date rounded to the given unit
     * @param date
     * @param unit
     * @return the rounded value
     */
    public static Date round(Date date,TimeUnit unit) {
        long dateInMillies = date.getTime();
        long tzOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(dateInMillies);
        long dateInMilliesWithoutOffset = dateInMillies + tzOffset;
        long dateInUnit = unit.convert(dateInMilliesWithoutOffset,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        long dateInMilliesRoundedWithoutOffset = unit.toMillis(dateInUnit);
        long dateInMilliesRoundedWithOffset = dateInMilliesRoundedWithoutOffset - tzOffset;
        return new Date(dateInMilliesRoundedWithOffset);
    }
```

And my unit test is:

```
@Test
    public void testRoundDate() {
        Date currentDayDate = new Date();
        Date currentDayBegin = DateUtils.getDayBegin(currentDayDate); // returns 00h00:00 and 000 milliseconds
        Date currentDayEnd = DateUtils.getDayEnd(currentDayDate,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // returns 23h59:59 and 999 milliseconds
        //
        final Calendar initialCalBegin = Calendar.getInstance();
        initialCalBegin.setTime(currentDayBegin);
        final Calendar initialCalEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
        initialCalEnd.setTime(currentDayEnd);
        //
        Calendar testedCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        //
        testedCalendar.setTime( DateUtils.round(currentDayBegin, TimeUnit.DAYS) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 0 );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 0 );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), 0 );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), 0 );
        testedCalendar.setTime( DateUtils.round(currentDayEnd, TimeUnit.DAYS) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 0 );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 0 );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), 0 );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), 0 );
        //
        testedCalendar.setTime( DateUtils.round(currentDayBegin, TimeUnit.HOURS) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 0 );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), 0 );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), 0 );
        testedCalendar.setTime( DateUtils.round(currentDayEnd, TimeUnit.HOURS) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 0 );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), 0 );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), 0 );
        // 
        testedCalendar.setTime( DateUtils.round(currentDayBegin, TimeUnit.MINUTES) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.MINUTE) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), 0 );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), 0 );
        testedCalendar.setTime( DateUtils.round(currentDayEnd, TimeUnit.MINUTES) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.MINUTE) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), 0 );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), 0 );
        //
        testedCalendar.setTime( DateUtils.round(currentDayBegin, TimeUnit.SECONDS) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.MINUTE) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.SECOND) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), 0 );
        testedCalendar.setTime( DateUtils.round(currentDayEnd, TimeUnit.SECONDS) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.MINUTE) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.SECOND) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), 0 );
        //
        testedCalendar.setTime( DateUtils.round(currentDayBegin, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.MINUTE) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.SECOND) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), initialCalBegin.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) );
        testedCalendar.setTime( DateUtils.round(currentDayEnd, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.MINUTE) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.SECOND) );
        Assert.assertEquals( testedCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), initialCalEnd.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) );
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // The TimeUnits under the millisecond precision should not procude any change to the date
        Assert.assertEquals(DateUtils.round(currentDayBegin, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS) , currentDayBegin);
        Assert.assertEquals(DateUtils.round(currentDayEnd, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS) , currentDayEnd);
        Assert.assertEquals(DateUtils.round(currentDayDate, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS) , currentDayDate);
        //
        Assert.assertEquals(DateUtils.round(currentDayBegin, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) , currentDayBegin);
        Assert.assertEquals(DateUtils.round(currentDayEnd, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) , currentDayEnd);
        Assert.assertEquals(DateUtils.round(currentDayDate, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) , currentDayDate);
    }
```

It seems what i've done works fine and is quite elegant.
However i'm not used to use timezones, and i wonder if this code works fine on very specific cases.
For exemple, do you see something that could happen a given day, for a country that has an offset change in its timezone?
Please tell me if you think something in wrong in my code.

Can i safely create a new method that takes a TimeZone parameter and can thus round a date to a given unit on a given timezone?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11997/most-elegant-way-to-round-a-date-to-a-dynamic-unit-of-time-using-only-jdk-6